# Java: Repeat Task Every Random Seconds

Tags: java, repeat

I'm already familiar with repeating tasks every n seconds by using Java.util.Timer and Java.util.TimerTask. But lets say I want to print "Hello World" to the console every random seconds from 1-5. Unfortunately I'm in a bit of a rush and don't have any code to show so far. Any help would be apriciated.

Comment: Lets say you do want to print `"Hello World"` to the console every random seconds. What's the question?

Answer (score 3):

Let's do it in 2 steps:

get a random number between 1 and 5

schedule your timer until this number in order to call the function

```
static Timer timer = new Timer();

static class TimTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        int delay = (1 + new Random().nextInt(4)) * 1000;
        timer.schedule(new TimTask(), delay);
        System.out.println("Hello world..!");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new TimTask().run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a good way to start...

```
Random r = new Random();
while(...){
    printHelloWorld();
    //calculate a random int between 1 and 5 and multiply for 1000
    Thread.sleep(r);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. But if you can't use Java 8 you have to replace the lambda expression with an anonymous class.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Time {
  final static Random rand = new Random();

  private static void _repeatRandom(Timer timer, long min, long max, int count, Runnable r) {
    if(count < 1) {
      timer.cancel();
      return;
    }
    long delay = (long)(rand.nextDouble() * (max - min)) + min;
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
        r.run();
        _repeatRandom(timer, min, max, count - 1, r);
      }
    }, delay);
  }

  static void repeatRandom(long min, long max, int count, Runnable r) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    _repeatRandom(timer, min, max, count, r);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    repeatRandom(1000, 5000, 10, () -> System.out.println("Hello World"));
  }
}
```

This code prints "Hello World" 10 times and waits between 1 and 5 seconds each time.